# C# Reflection with generics

Tags: c#, generics, reflection

I have been searching for this for some time but not gotten anywhere. I want to do the following:

Given a type say `Dictionary<string,MyClass>` and say its method `ContainsKey(string)` - at run time
I want to be able to extract out the 'Generic signature' of this method. That is I want to get
`Boolean Dictionary<TKey,TValue>.ContainsKey(TKey)` ( and not `Boolean ContainsKey(string)` )

I know that this is possible by doing the following

```
var untyped_methods = typeof(DictObject).GetGenericTypeDefition().GetMethods();
// and extract the method info corresponding to ContainsKey
```

However is is possible to get this information directly from the methods reflected from the
actual type and not from the Generic types ? Meaning Can I get the generic definition
from methods that have been obtained as follows :

```
var actual_typed_methods = typeof(DictObject).GetMethods()
```

In essence is it possible to get the "***un-typed***" method signatures from MethodInfo objects returned in the second snippet above directly (not via comparing the lists and figuring out)

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

***EDIT: Maybe this did what you wanted. Not sure if you were actually looking to `Invoke` or not.***

If Invoking, then no (see below). If you just want the definition, then you can use `typeof(Dictionary<,>)` to get the raw generic definitions.

---

Unfortunately, no if you are wanting to `Invoke`.

Demonstration of why:

```
void Main()
{
    var genericDictionaryType = typeof(Dictionary<,>);
    var method = genericDictionaryType.GetMethod("ContainsKey");
    var dict = new Dictionary<string, string>();

    dict.Add("foo", "bar");
    Console.WriteLine("{0}", method.Invoke(dict, new[] { "foo" }));
}
```

Yields the following error:

> Late bound operations cannot be performed on types or methods for which ContainsGenericParameters is true.

Sounds simple enough to fix. Just call `method.MakeGenericMethod(typeof(string));` to get the actual typed `MethodInfo` object.

Unfortunately again, you cannot.

> Boolean ContainsKey(TKey) is not a GenericMethodDefinition. MakeGenericMethod may only be called on a method for which MethodBase.IsGenericMethodDefinition is true.

Reason for this is because the method defined as `bool ContainsKey(TKey)` instead of `bool ContainsKey<TKey>(TKey)`.

You will need to get the `ContainsKey` method from the correct `Dictionary<TK,TV>` signature in order to use it.

Comment: No - I did not want to Invoke - just reflect and get the complete signature of various functions but without the generics. The method you suggested (typeof(Dictionary<,>) is similar to the first code snippet above - I was wondering if I can get the 'untyped' MethodInfo versions from the 'typed' MethodInfo objects.

Comment: @neo Okay good. Then `typeof(Dictionary<,>)` will do what you want.